# composer setup in windows 8

Tags: php, ssl, xampp, composer-php

I'm trying to install Composer-Setup for Windows but installation with an error and not continue

this error:

> Connection Error [ERR_CONNECTION]: Unable to connect to
>   getcomposer.org Request to https://getcomposer.org/installer failed
>   with errors: SSL: Handshake timed out. Failed to enable crypto. Failed
>   to open stream: operation failed

- version php :5.6.8
- xampp
- windows 8

Comment: Did you follow these instructions: http://www.codecheese.com/2015/02/installing-composer-xampp-windows/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the solution:

Ensure that the SSL certs are installed and can be found by PHP.

In `php.ini`:

```
curl.cainfo=/path/to/ssl-certs/ca-bundle.crt
openssl.cafile=/path/to/ssl-certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

If certs are missing: download a cert bundle from http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and save as `ca-bundle.crt`.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that opnessl configured and works,however, it didn't work.

but I used **v.p.n** & everything works like clock ;)